# Objective-C: data not returned as JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, ios7

My code looks like

```
+ (void)getAuthenticationToken {
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSLog(@"getting authentication token");

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [RestHelper getManager];
    [manager POST:[appUrl stringByAppendingString:tokenEndpoint]
       parameters:[self getTokenParameters:userDefaults]
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
              NSLog(@"authToken: %@", responseObject);
              [userDefaults setValue:responseObject[kAuthToken] forKey:kAuthToken];
          } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            }];

}
```

where `RestHelper` looks like

```
NSString *const registerEndpoint = @"oauth/register";
NSString *const tokenEndpoint = @"oauth/token";

NSString *const applicationJsonType = @"application/json";
NSString *const contentTypeHeader = @"Content-Type";
NSString *const acceptHeader = @"accept";

@implementation RestHelper {
}
+ (AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *)getManager {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:applicationJsonType forHTTPHeaderField:contentTypeHeader];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:applicationJsonType forHTTPHeaderField:acceptHeader];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:applicationJsonType];
    return manager;
}
@end
```

and `getTokenParameters` looks like

```
+ (NSDictionary *)getTokenParameters:(NSUserDefaults *)userDefaults {
    return @{kClientId : [userDefaults stringForKey:kClientId],
            kClientSecret : [userDefaults stringForKey:kClientSecret],
            @"authCode" : @"authCode"}; 
}
```

When I run the code, I get

```
2014-11-15 22:16:06.443 myapp-ios[50047:70b] authToken: {
    authToken = "228039536488452958553133702581187109931:78f7f8a4-a8c9-454a-93a8-6633a1076781:667000000";
}
```

However, when I hit the `API` via `command-line`, it returns `JSON`

```
curl -d'{"clientId":"111322610106743984083443169763434312591","clientSecret":"255682200164339900511209955730378006963", "authCode": "316425158197803351017336303318927150146"}' -H"Content-Type: application/json" https://myapp.com/oauth/token
{"authToken":"228039536488452958553133702581187109931:78f7f8a4-a8c9-454a-93a8-6633a1076781:667000000"}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Specifically what is not working? What is the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API **does** return JSON, only you don't see it because you are using `AFNetworking` which parses the JSON into an `NSDictionary` for you.

> ```
> 2014-11-15 22:16:06.443 myapp-ios[50047:70b] authToken: {
>     authToken = "228039536488452958553133702581187109931:78f7f8a4-a8c9-454a-93a8-6633a1076781:667000000";
> }
> ```

...this log coming from the line `NSLog(@"authToken: %@", responseObject);` means that `responseObject` contains an `NSDictionary` with the *key* `authToken` and the *value* `228039536488452958553133702581187109931:78f7f8a4-a8c9-454a-93a8-6633a1076781:667000000`.